# n(P(P(B))) How to get 256?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Set B has 3 elements.

Therefore,

it should be 2x2x3=12

2^12=4096

But answer is 256.

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For all finite sets with cardinality say $n$, the cardinality of its power set is given by $2^n$.

Hence for B, the power set of B has $2^3=8$ elements.

To find the number of elements in $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(B))$, we apply the formula one more time to get $2^8=256$.